# Работа с регулярными выражениями и импортом

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, импорт

Пользователь вводит номер действия и я хочу сделать проверку на ввод (удалить буквы и знаки).

Код:

```
num = str(input("Введите номер действия: "))
if num == '': # проверка на пустую строку
    print ('Вы ввели пустую стоку, пожалуйста повторите ввод')
else:
    number = re.findall('\d', num)
    number = ''.join(map(str, number))
```

Если запускаю код то все работает. Если запускаю код через дебагер, то:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\институт\лето 1 курс\питон\налоговая база v.3\Налоговая база.py", line 525, in
>   
>       hello()
>
> File "C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\институт\лето 1
>   курс\питон\налоговая база v.3\Налоговая база.py", line 33, in hello
>       number = re.findall('\d', num)
>
> File "C:\Остальное\Python 3.6.6\lib\re.py", line 222, in findall
>       return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
>
> File "C:\Остальное\Python 3.6.6\lib\re.py", line 301, in _compile
>       p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
>
> File "C:\Остальное\Python 3.6.6\lib\sre_compile.py", line 562, in
>   compile
>       p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
>
> File "C:\Остальное\Python 3.6.6\lib\sre_parse.py", line 855, in
>   parse
>       p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
>
> File "C:\Остальное\Python 3.6.6\lib\sre_parse.py", line 416, in
>   _parse_sub
>       not nested and not items))
>
> File "C:\Остальное\Python 3.6.6\lib\sre_parse.py", line 472, in
>   _parse
>       subpattern = SubPattern(state)
>
> File "C:\Остальное\Python 3.6.6\lib\sre_parse.py", line 112, in
>   **init**
>       self.pattern = pattern
>
> File "C:\Остальное\Python 3.6.6\lib\sre_parse.py", line 112, in
>   **init**
>       self.pattern = pattern
>
> File "C:\Остальное\Python 3.6.6\lib\bdb.py", line 51, in
>   trace_dispatch
>       return self.dispatch_line(frame)
>
> File "C:\Остальное\Python 3.6.6\lib\bdb.py", line 69, in
>   dispatch_line
>       self.user_line(frame)
>
> File "C:\Остальное\Python 3.6.6\lib\idlelib\debugger.py", line 24,
>   in user_line
>       self.gui.interaction(message, frame) AttributeError: 'SubPattern' object has no attribute 'data'

Хотелось бы понять в чем ошибка и как ее исправить. Я полагаю, что проблема либо в импорте, либо в неверном пути до модулей. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `"...Я полагаю, что проблема либо в импорте, либо в неверном пути до модулей..."` но импорт я вам не покажу, да? :) А как вы через дебагер код запускали? Думаю, в вашем коде нет проблем. Бага в дебагере

Comment: Импорт обычный import re. Запуск через дебагер с отображением построчно.

Comment: Хорошо, а что за дебагер и как его вызываете?

Comment: Стандартный дебагер (Debag concole) вшитый в питон

Comment: ` А как вы через дебагер код запускали?`

Comment: Ну открываю дебагер, выбираю в нем stack, locals, source и запускаю сам код в idle. Далее дохожу до этого момента ввожу значение и вот

Comment: Сейчас проверил через дебагер pycharm-а. Там другая ошибка:

Error evaluating: thread_id: pid_12376_id_2667425216552

frame_id: 2667435703912

scope: FRAME

attrs: this

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Остальное\PyCharm\PyCharm Community Edition 

2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_vars.py", line 248, in 

resolve_compound_variable_fields

    return _typeName, resolver.get_dictionary(var)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_dictionary'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input() - всегда возвращает str()
можно и без регулярок

```
def f():
    print('hello')


# словарь с номерами действий и функциями
action_dict = {
    '1': f,
    '2': f,
    '3': f,
    '4': f
}

while True:
    num = input('Введите номер действия: ')
    try:
        if num == '':
            raise ValueError('Вы ввели пустую стоку, пожалуйста'
                             ' повторите ввод')
        # 'q' - для выхода из программы
        # если не нужно выходить, то просто удалить "and num != 'q'"
        elif not num.isdigit() and num != 'q':
            raise TypeError('Вы ввели неверную команду')
        elif num.isdigit():
            # диапозон выбора действий
            if int(num) not in range(1, 5):
                raise ValueError('Вы ввели неверную команду')
            else:
                for key, value in action_dict.items():
                    if key == num:
                        value()
                # после выполнения действия программа завершается
                break
        else:
            print('Вы покинули программу')
            break
    except TypeError as t_err:
        print(t_err)
    except ValueError as v_err:
        print(v_err)
```

с re

```
import re


def f():
    print('hello')


action_dict = {
    '1': f,
    '2': f,
    '3': f,
    '4': f
}

while True:
    num = input('Введите номер действия:\n>>> ')
    PATTERN = r'\d'
    number = re.findall(PATTERN, num)
    number = ''.join(map(str, number))
    try:
        if num == '':
            raise ValueError('Вы ввели пустую стоку, пожалуйста'
                             ' повторите ввод')
        elif not number and num != 'q':
            raise TypeError('Вы ввели неверную команду')
        elif number:
            if int(number) not in range(1, 5):
                raise ValueError('Вы ввели неверную команду')
            else:
                for key, value in action_dict.items():
                    if key == number:
                        value()
                break
        else:
            print('Вы покинули программу')
            break
    except TypeError as t_err:
        print(t_err)
    except ValueError as v_err:
        print(v_err)
```

Comment: Это хороший метод, но как быть если нужно использовать регулярные выражения?

Comment: добавил решение с регулярным выражением.

Comment: Да это работает при обычном запуске, а при работе с дебагером выдаёт ту же ошибку о чем я и писал. И хотелось бы понять - почему? Пробовал  python 3.7, python 3.6.6